# in vim how do I make a keyboard shortcut to automatically insert a few sentences of text?

Tags: vim

in vim how do I make a keyboard shortcut to automatically insert a few sentences of text?

For example

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This in your vimrc/.vimrc file

```
inoremap HHH <html><cr>  <head><cr>  </head><cr>  <body><cr>  </body><cr></html>
```

Then in insert mode you can type HHH and it will type

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion) and [this comparison by Mark Weber](http://vim-wiki.mawercer.de/wiki/topic/text-snippets-skeletons-templates.html).

There are three things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others; third, how easy it is to add new snippets.